# Formating a javascript object not to display extra locale information

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to bind data from the database to an html page. I am using ms ajax templates to do this . The problem comes when i try to bind and format a date object.The following is a snippet of my code

```
 <p class="font1 pad_bot1">
     <a href="" sys:datadesc="{{StartDate}}" sys:dataid="{{ID}}">
         {{new Date(StartDate).toString("fullDate")}}
     </a>
```

The result of this code on my front end is as follows:

```
Thu Aug 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

I want to display the '**Thu Aug 01 2013** ' part only not the other part. I need a solution of how i can format the date without writing a function to do so. I am assuming javascript can do that out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about ms ajax templates. But assuming that the `Date` format behaves the same as in standard javascript, you can format your date manually. You can find more instructions [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3).

If you have a lot of date formatting to do, you may want to check [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: In what browser does that happen?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString Paremeters: none

Comment: I have edited my answer, I've had it all wrong indeed initially. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Tried the code and wasn't sure if date format in toString was now supported in some browsers. Firefox and mdn didn't mention it so I was curious if any other browser had it.

Comment: No, we have overwritten `toString` for dates at work to allow for formatting, hence the initial mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by simply doing this

{{new Date(StartDate).format('dddd, MMM , yyyy')}}

I used the format() function instead of toString(). Thank you for your contributions

Answer (score 0):

The best option for all international users is to use `toLocaleDateString`.

```
var date = new Date("Thu Aug 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200");
var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString(); 
// dateString will be "7/31/2013" in the US, but customized based on client's location
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString